# Create column Name Dynamically based on another column's Value, in SPROC

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SPROC as below. What I need is to have *new column names to be added dynamically* based on the value of the other column.
The column `[MyDynamicColumn]` (in the '*TJT.DColumn4 AS MyDynamicColumn*') should be in fact a combination of `'MyDinamicColumn'` and the value from column `[ProdName]` in the same row.

And I cannot figure out how to do it.

I was trying to use STUFF function, but it did not work (or maybe I'm not doing it the right way).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
        T1.ProdSpecialID,
        T1.ProdName AS ProdName,
        T1.Column3 AS MyColumn3,
        TJT.DColumn4 AS MyDynamicColumn
    FROM [MyTable1](@LanguageCode) AS T1
    INNER JOIN --TJT
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            T.ProdSpecialID,
            MSTS.NewColumn1 AS MyDynamicColumn
        FROM [dbo].[MyProductsTable] AS MPT
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MySalesTable] AS MST ON MST.ID = MPT.ID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MyServicesTable] AS MSTS ON MSTS.ID = MST.ID 
            AND MSTS.ServID = MST.ServID    
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MyInterestTable] AS T ON T.IntID = MSTS.IntID 
        WHERE
            MPT.DateCreated >= @StartDate
            AND MPT.DateCreated < @StopDate
        
        UNION

        SELECT DISTINCT
            T.ProdSpecialID,
            '' AS MyDinamicColumn
        FROM [dbo].[MyProductsTable] AS MPT
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MyDiscountTable] AS MDT ON MDT.ID = MPT.ID
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MyDiscountAndCouponTables] AS MDACT ON
            MDACT.ID = MDT.ID
            AND MDACT.CouponID = MDT.CouponID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MyInterestTable] AS T ON T.IntID = MDACT.IntID
        WHERE
            MPT.DateCreated >= @StartDate
            AND MPT.DateCreated < @StopDate
    ) AS TJT ON TJT.ProdSpecialID = T1.ProdSpecialID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT
        MSASPT.MySpecialProductID AS ProdSpecialID,
        MSASPT.ProdName AS ProdName,
        0 AS MyColumn3,
        '' AS MyDynamicColumn
    FROM [dbo].[MyProductsTable] AS MPT
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[MyDiscountTable] AS MDT ON MDT.ID = MPT.ID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[MySalesAndSpecialProductsTable] AS MSASPT ON
        MSASPT.ID = MDT.ID
        AND MSASPT.Priority = MDT.Priority
    WHERE
        MPT.DateCreated >= @StartDate
        AND MPT.DateCreated < @StopDate;
```

Comment: A column has a single name - it cannot vary row-by-row so your goal seems to be impossible. And now is a good time to unlearn a terrible habit - 9stop splattering your code with nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). If you KNOW it is needed, at least use current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: And one more suggestion. Your code is very difficult to read with all those unneeded square brackets. Code that is difficult to read encourages mistakes and mis-assumptions.

Comment: Thanks @SMor The goal is actually to add a new column - based on the value in the other column. I thought square brackets make those more clear. I have fixed it.